# Microsoft Indic Input 3 is not working with Win UI 3 (Windows App SDK) application Textbox

Tags: winapi, winui-3, ime, keyboard-layout, windows-app-sdk

I am developing a Winui 3 (Windows App SDK) application in which I need a Hindi input functionality in textbox with Remington GAIL keyboard Layout, from my research I found that the Hindi Indic Input  3 tool has this, I have installed this tool but it is not working with my application, but whereas it works with other Winforms (Windows Forms) application, Can anyone please help me out in this regard.

[Hindi Indic Input 3 is showing disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE0Lh.png)